# How must I print a value inside a nested dictionary without being too broad

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, iteration

I have a nested dictionary that was created through iteration, the values of the dictionary that HAS BEEN nested in another dictionary are unknown to me. So, without the keys/values being hardcoded in, how can I iterate through the dictionaries to pick a specific value to print?

Here's what I have in pseudocode (copying and pasting even chunks of the code would be nightmarish):

- dataDict is my main dictionary
- a loop runs however many times I have columns of data (that was a gross-sounding sentence, ex: runs 15 times if I have 15 columns of data)
- this loop creates another dictionary first, called rowInfo. rowInfo is then hardcoded with different calculation values (rowInfo['Min'] = calculations.getMin(data[n]), etc.)
- I then make dataDict[headers[n]] = rowInfo, thus taking the dictionary I just created and making it equal to one value of the main dictionary

Then, here is my code to print the data (if any variables don't make sense I can explain):

```
n = 0
  while n < len(headers):
    print("{:>11}".format(headers[n]),"|", "{:>10.2f}".format(dataDict[n].rowInfo['Min']), "|", "{:>10.2f}".format(dataDict[n].rowInfo['Max']), "|", 
      "{:>10.2f}".format(dataDict[n].rowInfo['Mean']))
    n = n + 1
```

I am aware this is not the correct way to print nested dictionaries, but I haven't found anything in my research that gives an answer to my more specific request.

An example of the data I am trying to process is as follows:

> Mom, Dad, Son, Daughter
>   2, 3, 4, 5
>   6, 7, 8, 9
>   1, 3, 5, 7

The first row is the headers, which I have put into a list, and the remaining rows are the data at a certain point. However, I need the data from each column that corresponds to each header.

Comment: What does the data look like? Might you be better off using a different data structure?

Comment: @AMC It is a .csv file. Using lists and dictionaries only seems feasible.

Comment: Can you share some data, I'm having trouble making sense of the program.

Comment: @AMC I have made an edit, hope it helps a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume we have a nested dictionary like so. 
Using recursion we can print each value that itself is not a dictionary.

```
data = {
    'outer_dictionary_key_1' : {
        'inner_dictionary_key_1' : 'some_val_1_1',
        'inner_dictionary_key_2' : 'some_val_1_2',
    },
    'outer_dictionary_key_2' : {
        'inner_dictionary_key_1' : {
            'level_3_key' : 'level_3_value',
        },
        'inner_dictionary_key_2' : 'some_val_2_2',
    }
}


def PrintInnerValues(data):

    # check if given element is a dictionary:
    if type(data) is dict:

        # iterate over every key value pair in dictionary:
        for key, value in data.items():

            # recursively call function:
            PrintInnerValues(data[key])

    # otherwise print the value:
    else:
        print(data)


PrintInnerValues(data)
```

This will result in:

```
some_val_1_1
some_val_1_2
level_3_value
some_val_2_2
```

Comment: See, my program has to work whether there are 4 columns of data or 100 columns of data. This just seems too hardcoded to function like that...

Comment: By columns I assume you mean another nested dictionary? This is a problem for recursion. If so, let's see what we can do.

Comment: Well yes, sort of. It would mean another nested dictionary in the first dictionary. There would be another row in the proverbial dictionary table.

Comment: Great, I edited my answer. We can use it as a starting point and add more logic as needed. Would this approach solve your problem?

Comment: I'll give it a go and accept the answer if I come up with the solution. Thanks!